# Swept by gale-force wind

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

(Edited)Let's say a super typoon swept your house's roof by extremely strong wind(gale), and had been detached from the house itself. Can you say:

> "Our roof was **swept by gale-force wind** and was detached from where it had been placed."

Is the phrasing here correct?

Comment: Your question is not grammatical. You're mixing the active and passive voices.  Your quoted phrase is grammatically correct.

Comment: As smatterer says, you really want "swept *away*".  Also, the last phrase of your sentence is very odd.  "was detached from where it had been placed"?  Isn't a roof always on top of a house?  And "placed" is a strange choice of words, because it emphasizes the putting of the roof on the house.  Also, it would make more sense to say it was detached (from your house) before it was swept away, because right now it sounds like the roof was swept away and then detached.

Answer (score 2):

Your phrase as it is means the the the roof was swept clean (*ie.* things on the roof were pushed away like with a broom) by the wind.

If you want to say that the roof was removed you will need to say "... was swept off by .." or "... was swept away by ...".